# complexity proof with big-o

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

how can I prove that $f(n) = \frac{n^2 + n}{2} \in O(n^3)$ ?

I did it like this:

> for $n \ge 1$, it holds that:
>
> $\frac{n^2 + n}{2} \le n^2 + n \le n^2 + n^2 \le 2n^2 \le (2n^2)\times
>  n = 2n^3$
>
> $2n^3 < cn^3$ for any $c > 2$

but I'm not sure if this is enough, since I'm just ignoring the existence of some $n_0$ such that the inequality holds for any $n > n_0$.

Did I make any mistake? If the way I did is right, how can I find $n_0$ ?

If it isn't, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have shown that
$\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}
\le 2n^3
$,
you are done.

All you need to do
is to show that
there is a
$c > 0$
and $n_0 > 0$
such that
$\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}
\le cn^3
$
for $n \ge n_0$.
You have shown this
for $c = 2$
and $n_0 = 1$,
and this is enough.